# Adding custom buttons to ToolBar

Tags: java, android

I would like to know after all my time-wasting, how to add custom buttons to the toolbar/activitybar? If someone have the answer, can please he/she post it to me...

Comment: what you have searched

Comment: simply  search on google **custom layout in toolbar android**

Answer (score 2):

The toolbar is a ViewGroup, you can add any layout inside it. In the below-given example, I am using the LinearLayout.

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_overflow_menu_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In java, you can access the `Button` as

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_overflow_menu_button);
```

Making the button clickable in **Java** class

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
            }
        });
```

Comment: due to android:layout_width="match_parent" title remains under linearLayout

Comment: I would suggest using TextView inside the LinearLayout to set the title so that they are aligned and the boundary is properly set.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Toolbar` subclass of `ViewGroup` so you can put what ever views inside it

```
 <android.support...Toolbar
    android:layout_width=".."
android:layout_height=".."
    ..
    ...>

    <Button
android:layout_width=".."
android:layout_height=".." 
    ...
    ...
    />
    </android....Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom toolbar like below and add any View to your Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```